# Combine results of 2 commands in 1 output table

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

I need to make the below script show the `Test-Connection` for 3 times to.

The script is only showing the steps for the `Test-NetConnection`. The question is, how can I combine the `Test-Connection` and the Test-NetConnection` into this one table?

Here is the code:

```
$computers = "pc1", "pc2"

foreach ($pc in $computers) {
    $test_connection = try {
        Test-Connection $pc -Count 3 -ErrorAction Stop
    } catch {
        Write-Warning "->$pc<- is not responding!"
    }
    if ($test_connection) {
        Test-NetConnection $pc -Port 1433
        [PSCustomObject]@{
            Computername          = $test_connection.PSComputername
            'Problematic-server'  = $test_connection.Address;
            buffersize            = $test_connection.buffersize;
            'My Local IP Adress'  = $test_netconnection.SourceAddress;
            'problematic-servers' = $test_netconnection.ComputerName;
            RemoteAddress         = $test_netconnection.RemoteAddress;
            RemotePort            = $test_netconnection.RemotePort;
            TcpTestSucceeded      = $test_netconnection.TcpTestSucceeded
        } | Format-Table -AutoSize
    }
}
```

The result looks like that:

```
Computername                        Problematic-server                                                                                 buffersize   My Local IP Adress problematic-servers RemoteAddress RemotePort
------------                        ------------------                                                                                 ----------   ------------------ ------------------- ------------- -----
{loclpc-01, localpc-01, localpc-01} System.Object&, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=123456789 Address(int ) {32, 32, 32} blah-blah          blah-blah           192.168.0.0   1433
```

If I remove the `$test_connection` from the table, it's doing correctly the `Test-NetConnection` procedure, otherwise it's showing this strange answer.

Comment: `try{Test-Connection $pc -Count -3 -ErrorAction Stop}` --> `try{Test-Connection $pc -Count 3 -ErrorAction Stop}`. I guess you don't intend to get the count as minus 3(-3). PowerShell will treat -3 as a parameter and hence your code will not be evaluated. As a result `$test_connection` will be empty.

Comment: damnnn it was a typo !!
thanks man !!!!! I LOVE YOU !

Comment: You never assign the output of `Test-NetConnection` to the variable `$test_netconnection` that you're using when building your custom objects. Basically, it's not possible that the code you posted gave you the output you posted. Also, your question has nothing to do with [splatting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_splatting?view=powershell-3.0).